# Can't get innerHTML to work in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to dynamically change the content of some HTML element on a page. For the purpose of this question I have boiled it down to some very simple code:

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Changed!";
   alert(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

This works when called just in a simple HTML file. But not, if this is put into a wordpress page. See it here: https://klaerchen-coaching.de/bewerbung/dummy/

When you click on the paragraph, the function is called and the content of the `<p>` is updated, as can be seen by the alert() message. But on screen, nothing changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: can u tell me what needs to be happen on click of <p>. When I inspect element the code, I could see a font attribute inside the above <p> tag. Are you aware of it?

Comment: When I click on the <p> its content should change to the word "changed!"

This works as a standalone HTML, but not in wordpress. The font-attribute might be inherited, I guess.

Comment: @Gopinath Shiva, great point, just seems like he's looking for non-jquery solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another p with id "demo" on your page

[image: Look at here]

It located before the "p" you want to change and it has changed.
That div is invisible as you can see because of left:-9999px;

How to debug this:

1. Set breakpoint in chrome dev tools on the line your "p" is going to
   change
2. Put document.getElementById("demo") to watches
3. Check the parent of found "p", check if it that "p" you expect

Delete that hidden "div" and check again. Then your code is going to work fine.

Comment: Wow, that's it! There was a plugin obviously duplication the whole page for the purpose of creating a printable version. When I deactivate it it works. Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy!

Comment: Thank you so much again! Also for the helpful steps how to detect this next time. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is execution was refused by `klaerchen-coaching`.
Here is the message which you'll recieve if you click on text in developer console. So you'd better to keep that open when developing.

> klaerchen-coaching.de/:120 Refused to execute inline event handler
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline
>   execution.

Answer (score -1):

### May be your jquery not working on that page

### try use wp_footer(); in footer.php

and

### wp_header(); in header.php hope this will work

### also check id is used one time on that page